# How to prevent an external JS request

Tags: javascript

I'm using a service that automatically constructs and hosts launch pages. In the body of their code, they have a call to jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js?cache=2015-09-22-09">
```

Unfortunately, since I'm in China, googleapis.com is blocked and the page has to wait for this code to timeout before it will render. This portion is autogenerated as part of the template and I can't change it. However I can insert custom javascript in the head and the body.

Are there any ways I can prevent this code from making the request to googleapis.com or to force it to abort after it has already made the request?

-EDIT-

Here's a screen cap of the network tab when I try to load the page. As you can see, the call to googleapis.com hangs for 1.4 mins until it times out, at which point DomContentLoaded triggers and the entire page loads.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, are you able to insert custom code in the head _above_ this `<script>` tag?

Comment: Can't you comment it out if a user is in china? `<!-- -->`

Comment: @JamesThorpe I'm not sure how that would help.  At first I thought you were going to propose that they find the `<script>` element and remove it before it starts to load anything, but in practise that's not how browsers work.  The element won't exist until the page parser reaches that part of the page, by which time it's too late.

Comment: @Alnitak It was more along the lines of ahmad's approach - depending on where things can be injected, it may be possible to remove entire blocks using comments, then just add back in the things you're interested in

Comment: @JamesThorpe using `document.write()` to insert the comments to prevent any later content from being parsed until you want it to be?

Comment: @Alnitak It depends on what is injectable and where.  Unfortunately it doesn't look like the OP is hanging around to let us know...

Comment: shame - it's an interesting question!

Comment: @Alnitak Yep.  Perhaps SO just got blocked too...

Comment: Intriguing! It sounds like he is able to insert custom code into the head. He said in the body of their code they have the jQuery call, and he can insert custom javascript in the head and body. Most likely, he has control of the page and the included service is inserted in the dom with scripts and all. If so, in theory, higher dom placed javascript could work.

Comment: Hey! Sorry I didn't think the replies would be so fast! The troublesome script tag is in the body and I am able to insert custom Javascript in the head before this tag or in the body after this tag.

Comment: I've tried to do a search for the tag and remove it but as @Alnitak mentioned earlier, the way the DOM loads makes this method not work

Comment: Can you use `server-side` code ? **Pre-prosess hypertext** ?

Comment: I cannot. This service is along the lines of Weebly or Unbounce. It allows you to create a landing page via a WYSIWYG editor and host it on their servers but doesn't give you any freedom in changing their backend code. They do, however, allow you to insert custom Javascript into the header and the body.

Comment: Can't the service staff help you (i.e. do they offer any kind of support) ? If you can only touch javascript, you aren't likely to be able to do anything about it.

Comment: Yeah I've written to support, and am awaiting a response. I'm not sure they'll be willing to change their backend code just to accommodate Chinese users. In the meantime, I've been searching for various ways that Javascript might allow me to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you post what exact response do you get in console?

Comment: @enfieldacademy where *precisely* in the document can you insert code relative to the existing `<script>` tag?

Comment: If you are the sole visitor to the site, you could block the ajax.googleapis.com domain using a hosts record.

`127.0.0.1 ajax.googleapis.com`

Then the request would fail immediately.

Comment: Considering china has a huge population, yes, they should be willing to change it "just for the few" chinese people on earth.

Comment: @Alnitak

<head>
can insert code here
</head>
<body>
<troublesome call to googleapi for jQuery>
can also insert code here
</body>

Comment: @enfieldacademy If there is no valuable html between those two places, you can follow ahmad albayati's suggestion of opening a html comment in the first placeholder `<!--` and closing it in the second `-->`, thereby commenting out anything in between.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Right, if you are able to put html in the head of the document, not just execute javascript you could use a meta tag to block external script loading:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'">
```

From the [Mozilla Content-Security-Policy Meta Tag Docs](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/content-security-policy/#delivery-html-meta-element):

> Authors are strongly encouraged to place meta elements as early in the document as possible, because policies in meta elements are not applied to content which preceds them. In particular, note that resources fetched or prefetched using the Link HTTP response header field, and resources fetched or prefetched using link and script elements which precede a meta-delivered policy will not be blocked.

So the meta tag will only work in the head, certainly before the script which loads jQuery. You can whitelist URL's in the tag by adding them into the content parameter in the meta tag too.

If you can only execute javascript, you can add the meta tag dynamically. Unfortunately it is likely the browser has probably decided on it's policies by the time it is added. Nevertheless, it can be added with

```
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.httpEquiv = "Content-Security-Policy";
meta.content = "script-src 'self'";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```

More Interesting reading material homework for solving the 'Prevent an external js request' mystery:

[Use JavaScript to prevent a later `<script>` tag from being evaluated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726362/use-javascript-to-prevent-a-later-script-tag-from-being-evaluated)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 7):

Consider using a [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy). It would be an unusual use case, but with the CSP you can tell the browser that it is not allowed to access googleapis.com before your government even gets a say in the matter. In this way, the browser won't even try to load it, and the page will not hang.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I think I may have been a bit vague with my wording. I'm editing a locked down template that is served to other people. I would like to prevent this template from calling the googleapi call. I have the ability to insert custom javascript in the header and in the body of the template.

Comment: Hmm. I am inclined to say that there comes a time where you must draw the line. Stop trying to work around the oppressive restrictions of an arbitrary template, and make your own stuff. That way, any restrictions that you have (such as an inability to access Google) can be resolved in a sane manner. Seriously, consider how many hours you're going to spend (or *have* spent!) on this issue, compared to the amount of time you could save by just coding it yourself. Workarounds are a recipe for migraine later.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. @Niet's suggestion seems nice. To add to his answer, here's how you can block rendering of googleapi domain using CSP:

`Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self';`

This code would instruct the browser to only execute YOUR own domain's scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the web server and its windows you could add an entry in the Hosts file to redirect the google address to the local server web application to download the javascript from there? (if you match the folder structure of the javascript link)

```
c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts


ajax.googleapis.com 127.0.0.1
```