# Replace JavaScript functionality from another JS file

Tags: javascript

My webpage is including a .js file whose functionality I have to change/replace/expand.

I have the new JS all written out and included in my webpage, but I can't get it to overwrite the original script or prevent the original script from executing.

Assume I am unable to remove the original `<script>` element from the page, but I am able to include my new script before the original script.

EDIT: Here's how it's laid out:

```
<script src="my-new-script.js"></script>

<!-- Some HTML -->

<!-- I want to replace the functionality of the below script with 
"my-new-script.js" and/or prevent my-old-script.js from executing -->

<script src="my-old-script.js"></script>
```

The reason:
`my-old-script.js` is being loaded by a WordPress theme, and for my purposes I cannot change the theme or alter PHP files of the theme, so I cannot prevent `my-old-script.js` from being loaded. But, I can include `my-new-script.js` via Widgets

I looked at some of the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726362/use-javascript-to-prevent-a-later-script-tag-from-being-evaluated), but they didn't seem to apply to my scenario

Comment: Show relevant code to explain your issue more.

Comment: How is it possible that you can add your script but not remove the other script?

Comment: If you're including it before the original script, then it will be overwritten by that script...

Comment: So I answered this 2 hours ago. Did you look at my script?

Answer (score 1):

So I could not remove the script because it's functions were already saved in the window scope, but I could re-assign the function

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      //  document.querySelectorAll("script")[1].remove()
      window.myFunc = () => {
        console.log("my first func")
      }
    })
  </script>
  <script>
    function myFunc() {
      console.log("my second func")
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunc()">Click</button>
</body>

</html>
```