how to remove <script> from the page before it loads it contents
I have a page hosted on a server which injects small portion of script to my index.html page and would like to remove this script before it runs.
Simplified example looks like this
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body> 
<script id="removeme">
    console.log("go");
</script>
</body>
</html>

I want to prevent the 'console.log("go");' from being executed.
I have tried to add a script which removes the removeme script:


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
nothing to show
<script id="script_which_removes_the_other_script">
    // First attempt
    console.log("1 trying to remove " );
    const unwantedScript = document.getElementById('removeme');
    console.log("1 the script tag to remove: " + unwantedScript );
    if (unwantedScript) {
        unwantedScript.remove();
        console.log('1 Unwanted script removed.');
    }
    else{
     console.log('1 Did not found the script to remove.');
    }

    // Second attempt
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        console.log("2 trying to remove " );
        const unwantedScript = document.getElementById('removeme');
        console.log("2 the script tag to remove: " + unwantedScript );
        if (unwantedScript) {
            unwantedScript.remove();
            console.log('2 Unwanted script removed.');
        }
     });
</script>
<script id="removeme">
    console.log("go");
</script>
</body>
</html>



But neither block 1, neither block 2 cannot stop the method from being run.
The console output is as follows:
1 trying to remove 
1 the script tag to remove: null
1 Did not found the script to remove.
go
2 trying to remove 
2 the script tag to remove: [object HTMLScriptElement]
2 Unwanted script removed.

How can I prevent the function from the removeme block from being run?

const unwantedScript = document.getElementById('removeme'); executed "inline", before the target element exists in DOM order, won't find it; and with DOMContentLoaded, you are likely too late already. There isn't a really easy way to do this.

@C3roe yes the explanation you give makes a lot of sense. I am happy to hear also "uneasy" way if it exists:)

For an inline script as in the example above, I don't know if there is anything you can do to reliably remove it. If it was a script loaded from an external source, a service worker that intercepts requests, could prevent the browser from fetching the script URL. Not sure if that is worth the effort though, resp. the side effects this could potentially have on other functionality.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726362/use-javascript-to-prevent-a-later-script-tag-from-being-evaluated

Try a more aggressive approach by removing the script element immediately as soon as it is created in the DOM.
Here is my approach, hope help you. Add the following code to the first script tag:
console.log("Attempting to remove the unwanted script.");

// Observe the document for any changes
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach((node) => {
      if (
        node.nodeType === 1 &&
        node.tagName === "SCRIPT" &&
        node.id === "removeme"
      ) {
        node.remove(); // Remove the unwanted script
        console.log("Unwanted script removed.");
      }
    });
  });
});

// Start observing the document
observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });

// Optionally disconnect the observer after some time or under certain conditions
setTimeout(() => observer.disconnect(), 5000);


This solution works perfect. Do you know if there are any drawbacks for it?

@fascynacja this implementation is solid and efficient for many scenarios however there is some drawbacks i can predict :there might be a brief moment when the unwanted script executes before the observer has a chance to remove it. - The observer disconnects after 5 seconds If the unwanted script is added after this period, it won't be detected or removed - performance overhead if many changes occur rapidly or frequently modified

is there any way to remove the script even before it was added to the DOM? in that way there will be no brief moment, when the script can execute?

@fascynacja i tried some other approaches, but none of them worked. Definitely, there are other ways to remove it before it's added to the DOM, although they may be challenging and not straightforward because they involve server-side handling, which is beyond my current knowledge as a front-end developer

If the <script> tag is injected server-side by searching for the closing </body> tag, then you could just not output it. Both the <html> tag and the <body> tag have optional end tags.
Another options is to have the browser block the script:
Browsers include CSP. A Content Security Policy tells the browser what types of content it should execute. You can disable all inline <script> tags and only allow your own <script> elements, either by linking them (<script src="">) or by including a nonce attribute:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
  content="script-src 'self' https: 'nonce-abc123'">

<body>

Only the first <tt>&lt;script&gt;</tt> element will be executed, 
the other will trigger an error in the browser console.

<script nonce="abc123">
console.log(1);
</script>

<script>
console.log(2);
</script>

This particular CSP value will allow <script> tags that come from the same server (/file.js), from https links (https://example.com/file.js) or if they include a nonce property with the value abc123. Note that the single quotes matter.
If the script you're trying to block is not inline but includes a src (<script src="">) then you remove either 'self' or https: from the policy (whichever is applicable) and add the nonce attribute to all of your own scripts.

This solution works indeed so I am happy to upvote the answer. Just the other answer from @Erfan is more convenient for me, because I can block the script directly from javascript and the truth is that I need to do it conditionaly : if(user_wants_statistics) then do_noting() else remove_the_script() . Unless you know if I can also use your solution in more dynamic way?

The solution with CSP could be conditional (just change the header's value dynamically server-side). I'd say a CSP is better if you're dealing with a situation where you don't know what will be injected (preventing MITM attacks, for example). MutationObserver is supported broadly and a perfectly fine solution for this problem. As it's a working solution and you've indicated it's more convenient for you, you should mark that answer as accepted.

Thank you for your kind explanation and for sharing this interesting points about Content Security Policy. I was not even aware that something like this exist. Taking all pros and cons I will use the MutationObserver .

Use defer: The defer attribute makes sure the script is executed after the HTML is parsed.
Use async: The async attribute allows the script to load and execute asynchronously.

Dear @Satya . I see this is one of your first answers on Stack Overflow and I thought maybe you need some help. I suggest to read some materials about how to answer questions so you will be able to support other with your knowledge in the best way. For instnace your answer is missing a runnig example, its not very clear how your solution should be implemented. All best!
